# Is it possible to use an rvalue reference as pimpl handle?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue-reference, pimpl-idiom

I want to create a class with a Pimpl (Private implementation). Normally you would do:

```
class A
{
private:
  class B;
  B* _pimpl = nullptr;
}
```

and then I would define it in the `.cpp` file. But I have to use dynamic allocation.  Would it be possible to use an rvalue reference instead?

```
class A
{
public:
  A(); //Constructor to init rvalue reference
private:
  class B;
  B&& _pimpl;
}
```

And then in the `.cpp` file:

```
class A::B
{
public:
   int C = 3u;
}

//and then the constructor of A:

A::A() : _pimpl(B()) { } //now we should have a fresh b pimpl?
```

I'm currently on holidays and I only have my C++ book for reference. I read about rvalue references and thought it might work. What do you guys think?

Comment: Why not a simple reference? Why do you think you need to move `B`?

Comment: because i tought in order to do A::A() : _pimpl(B()) { } - to construct B into _pimpl i have to use rvalue because B() is an rvalue? But im not sure if this is right - but would it work with a normal reference ?

Comment: [It seems you're right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3715e6792f498012). If a simple reference is used the [compiler complains](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07083e9a2d30066d).

Comment: Nitpick: "Pimpl (Private implemenation)" - Pimpl usually means "*Pointer* to implementation" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "work" you mean "compile", then sure.

But `_pimpl(B())` is going to initialize _pimpl as a reference to a *temporary*. Member references *don't* extend lifetime, so this construct dangles almost immediately. Therefore no, it won't work.

A `unique_ptr<B>` is the better type to hold a pimpl (as a default choice). The need for dynamic allocation cannot generally be avoided. But the drawbacks may be mitigated if one chooses a good custom allocator.

Comment: This is [one of several reasons] why I don't like this idiom: the near-mandated excessive dynamic allocations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The language of all the wrong defaults, innit? :)

Comment: Yes true indeed!